# How to load and use a persistent symmetric key in the TPM?

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing

I simply want to store one 32 bytes long symmetric key persistently in the NV storage of the TPM and after a power-cycle, use it (without getting it out of the TPM) to encrypt small-sized data.

I've tried to do that in two different ways:

1)

- Create the key with TPM's random bytes generator
- Define space in NV and write the key in it
- **Problem**: I know how to read it, but how can I load it so I can use it inside the TPM?

2)

- Create an AES key with TPM2_Create command
- Make it persistent with TPM2_EvictControl command
- Through the same power cycle, I have its handle and I can load it and use it
- **Problem**: Similar to before, How to load it and use it after the next power cycle?

I scanned [TCG's Specs](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/tpm-library-specification/) and I even read this [free practical guide to TPM2.0](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4302-6584-9.pdf) and haven't found any clues to my problems.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TPM2_EncryptDecrypt` is meant to be used with symmetric keys. Pass the key handle you obtained with the `TPM2_EvictControl` as the `@keyHandle` parameter, and set the `decrypt` parameter appropriately. Set `mode` to `TPM_ALG_NUL` so the default mode is used.

Keep in mind that it's not practical to use the TPM for encrypting large amounts of data (what symmetric keys are typically used for).

Comment: It works when I do it on the same run, on the next power cycle I need only the NV storage address and the extras if added (user auth, policy, etc)  am I correct?

Comment: No, you just use the key by its handle if your evict control was successful. You will need to satisfy a policy if you attached one to the key, and provide auth if needed.

Comment: OK, so for example I have only auth: Creating handle with TPM_HANDLE persistentHandle = TPM_HANDLE::PersistentHandle(addr), then set the auth with persistentHandle.SetAuth(password), and then use the handle? PS. I use Microsoft tss.

Comment: What is `addr`? There shouldn't be any address involved... make the handle persistent like here: https://github.com/microsoft/TSS.MSR/blob/98a7d56ba81c48d33086db84d7b6bc7b9474e8fc/TSS.CPP/Samples/Samples.cpp#L883

Comment: I meant handle offset, my mistake. Thank you for your help